# como saco esta informacion para que me la pinte en un select

Tags: array

necesito sacar la informacion que esta dentro del [object Object] o del obj['qualification'] contiene esta informacion 0:
name_conf_type_rating: "SI"
**proto**: Object
1:
name_conf_type_rating: "NO"
**proto**: Object
length: 2
**proto**: Array(0) y necesito que salgan en el select
asi esta formulada en NeatBeans
$("#divTdS" + obj['id']).append($('' + obj['qualification'] + ''));

asi se ve en elements

```
<select>[object Object],[object Object]</select>
```

Comment: Que es lo que contiene `obj['qualification']`?

Comment: 0: {name_conf_type_rating: "SI"}
1: {name_conf_type_rating: "NO"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: no puedes pintar la informacion de un array, necesitas iterar

Comment: como se hace eso ??

Comment: @user230521 ¿Cual es el resultado que esperas obtener? ¿Que dentro del select haya cada `option` de `obj['qualification']`?

Comment: Podrías agregar más información en tu pregunta por favor? Que problema tienes? Que es lo que deseas lograr? Cual es el mensaje de error?

Answer (score 1):

No puedes pintar la informacion de un array, necesitas iterar asi:

```
$("#divTdS" + obj['id']).append($('<select id="opciones"></select>');
obj['qualification'].each(function(i) {
    $("#opciones).append($('<option>' + i['name_conf_type_rating'] + '</option>'));
}):
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: no use `forEach`, sino `each`

Comment: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined

Comment: Eso quiere decir que no esta definido, pero segun lo que imprimiste si lo esta